# $-\frac{n}{16}\min(t, t^2) + 2\log m \le -\frac{n}{16}\min(\delta, \delta^2)$

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, proof-explanation

I've got an inequality to prove, which seems to require some tricks to solve.

> **Inequality**
> Under the contraint $n > \log m$ and $t = 8\sqrt{(\log m)/n} + \delta$, where $\delta > 0$ and $n,m \in \mathbb N$,
> $$\exp\{-\frac{n}{16}\min(t, t^2) + 2\log m\} \le \exp\{-\frac{n}{16}\min(\delta, \delta^2)\},$$

which is equivalent to $-\frac{n}{16}\min(t, t^2) + 2\log m \le -\frac{n}{16}\min(\delta, \delta^2)$.

I've got a partial proof of it, saying

> You may consider the case **$n > 16 \log m$** and the opposite one so that you can obtain the desired result.

But, for the first case,
$$\begin{align}
n > 16 \log m & \Leftrightarrow (\log m)/n < \frac{1}{16}\\
& \Leftrightarrow 8\sqrt{(\log m)/n} < 2,
\end{align}$$
and I'm not sure about how the result $8\sqrt{(\log m)/n} < 2$ can induce the desired result. (the number is not even less than 1, so it doesn't seem to be useful information as far as I know)

If I have to use $n > 16 \log m$ in a different way, or if there are some other approach or hints to handle the inequality, it would be grateful. Thank you.

Comment: As it is written right now the inequality is false. Unless I have done some error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the exponential is positive the inequalify becomes

$$\exp\{-\frac{n}{16}\min(t, t^2) + 2\log m+\frac{n}{16}\min(\delta, \delta^2)\} \le 1$$
Or
$$-\frac{n}{16}\min(t, t^2) + 2\log m+\frac{n}{16}\min(\delta, \delta^2) \le 0$$
**If $t, \delta>1$ the inequalify becomes**
$$-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{n\log(m)} + 2\log m \le 0
$$
And the inequalify is generally false (would be true if instead of $2\log(m)$ there would be $\frac{1}{2}\log(m)$ )

**If $t ,\delta <1$ the inequality becomes**
$$
-2 \log(m)-\delta \sqrt{n \log(m)} \le 0
$$
that is always satisfied

**If $t>1$, $\delta<1$ the inequality becomes**
$$
-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{n \log(m)}+ 2 \log(m) -\frac{n}{16} \left(\delta -\delta^2\right) \le 0
$$
As before this is in general false, unless there is a typo in the question and the correct value is $\frac{1}{2} \log(m)$ instead of $2 \log(m)$

As is of course impossible that $t<1$, $\delta>1$, these are all the possible cases

Comment: Your answer is right, my material should have some typos or errors. Thank you for the answer.